# Notepad++ remove character 10 to 20 for example

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

the title says it all, I can't find a option in notepad+ for removing for example character 10 to 20.

Do I miss something or is there a other option for it?

Example:

original line:

```
<div id="dot"><a id="69149d5ac2-70"  href="
```

must look like:

```
<div id="dot"><a href="
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking, but if you need to delete chars 10 to 20 of **each** line, a fast way of doing this is block selection.

You just keep <kbd>ALT</kbd> pressed while dragging to select a rectangular block of characters. Then hit <kbd>DEL</kbd> to delete them.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Notepad++ doesn't support `{i,j}` bounds for atom counts in regexes.

The following instructions will remove the string based on its contents. It may select other strings in your file that are similar so be careful with the Replace All button.

- Select Replace from the Search menu.
- In the Find What field enter: `(<a) id="[0-9a-f-]*"` (there's a space after the final quote).
- In the Replace With field enter `\1`.
- Select Regular Expression in the Search Mode box.
- Use Find Next, Replace and Replace All as needed.